# Filter ecg signal with wavelet

Tags: python, matlab, noise, wavelet

I'm working with an ECG signal and I want to delete the drift noise.
In Matlab it works fine this code:

```
[c, l]=wavedec(ecgsignal,8,'coif5'); 
a9=wrcoef('a',c,l,'coif5',8);
```

where ecgsignal is the original signal with noise and a9 is the filtered signal.
I'm trying to made the same in python with this code:

```
coeffs=pywt.wavedec(ecgsignal,'coif5', level=8)
renc=pywt.waverec(coeffs, 'coif5')
```

but the reconstructed signal, renc, has the noise.
Can someone help me to understand what is not correct? I use the wrong commands of the PyWavelet library?

Comment: It looks like you're feeding all of the decomposed coefficients into the reconstructing function.

Comment: I was going to comment the same thing. I'm not used to working with wavelets, only with FFT, but it seems you should reconstruct the signal with only **a few selected** coefficients, not them all.

Comment: As the example of the documentation of PyWavelet: coeffs = pywt.wavedec([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'db2', level=2)
print pywt.waverec(coeffs, 'db2') it ises all coefficients.

Comment: @GiuseppeRicci the documentation is showing that the two functions, wavedec and waverec, are perfectly inverse to each other.

Comment: @AndyKubiak is it the same in Matlab? Why this instructions doesn't work well in python?

Answer (score 3):

You are simply deconstructing the signal and then reconstructing the signal.  You have not done the key thresholding step that actually does the signal filtering that you are looking for.

A basic outline of the steps needed *sketched* in python:

```
// DWT
coeffs = pywt.wavedec(ecgsignal,'coif5', level=8); 
// Compute threshold something like this.  You need an estimate
// of the noise sigma.
threshold=noiseSigma*sqrt(2*log2(ecgsignal.size)); 
// Apply the threshold.  Pseudocode here.
newcoeffs = pywt.thresholding.soft( coeffs , threshold);
// IDWT
renc = pywt.wavedec(newcoeffs , 'coif5');
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, pywt has not implemented wrcoef equivalent function yet. But you still can decompose 1-D multilevel signal then reconstruct its components separately.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47591523/2845274