# Multilevel partial wavelet reconstruction with pyWavelets

Tags: python, pywt

I'm looking for a way to partially reconstruct branches of a wavelet decomposition, such that the sum would recreate the original signal. This could be achieved using Matlab using:

```
DATA = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
N_LEVELS = 2;
WAVELET_NAME = 'db4';
[C,L] = wavedec(DATA, N_LEVELS, WAVELET_NAME);
A2 = wrcoef('a', C, L, WAVELET_NAME, 2);
D2 = wrcoef('d', C, L, WAVELET_NAME, 2);
D1 = wrcoef('d', C, L, WAVELET_NAME, 1);
A2+D2+D1

ans =

    0.0000    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    4.0000    5.0000    6.0000    7.0000    8.0000    9.0000
```

I'd like to achieve the same using pywt, but I'm not sure how to go about this.
The `pywt.waverec` function creates a full reconstruction, but doesn't have a level parameter for partial reconstruction.
The `pywt.upcoef` function does what I need for a single level but I'm not sure how to expand this for multiple levels:

```
>>> import pywt
>>> data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> (cA, cD) = pywt.dwt(data, 'db2', 'smooth')
>>> n = len(data)
>>> pywt.upcoef('a', cA, 'db2', take=n) + pywt.upcoef('d', cD, 'db2', take=n)
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to write my own version of the `wrcoef` function which appears to work as expected:

```
import pywt
import numpy as np

def wrcoef(X, coef_type, coeffs, wavename, level):
    N = np.array(X).size
    a, ds = coeffs[0], list(reversed(coeffs[1:]))

    if coef_type =='a':
        return pywt.upcoef('a', a, wavename, level=level)[:N]
    elif coef_type == 'd':
        return pywt.upcoef('d', ds[level-1], wavename, level=level)[:N]
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid coefficient type: {}".format(coef_type))



level = 4
X = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
coeffs = pywt.wavedec(X, 'db1', level=level)
A4 = wrcoef(X, 'a', coeffs, 'db1', level)
D4 = wrcoef(X, 'd', coeffs, 'db1', level)
D3 = wrcoef(X, 'd', coeffs, 'db1', 3)
D2 = wrcoef(X, 'd', coeffs, 'db1', 2)
D1 = wrcoef(X, 'd', coeffs, 'db1', 1)
print A4 + D4 + D3 + D2 + D1

# Results:
[  9.99200722e-16   1.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+00
   4.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+00   6.00000000e+00   7.00000000e+00
   8.00000000e+00   9.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+01   1.10000000e+01
   1.20000000e+01   1.30000000e+01   1.40000000e+01   1.50000000e+01
   1.60000000e+01   1.70000000e+01]
```

Comment: This works well, however, I am a bit confused cause to my understanding the length of the data is supposed to reduce(by a factor of 2) as you increase the levels since you're decomposing the signals. But in this case, we are getting the same length as the original signal `X` at each level

Answer (score 2):

Currently, pywt has not implemented wrcoef equivalent function yet. But you still can decompose 1-D multilevel signal then reconstruct its components separately.

```
import pywt
def decomposite(signal, coef_type='d', wname='db6', level=9):
    w = pywt.Wavelet(wname)
    a = data
    ca = []
    cd = []
    for i in range(level):
        (a, d) = pywt.dwt(a, w, mode)
        ca.append(a)
        cd.append(d)
    rec_a = []
    rec_d = []
    for i, coeff in enumerate(ca):
        coeff_list = [coeff, None] + [None] * i
        rec_a.append(pywt.waverec(coeff_list, w))
    for i, coeff in enumerate(cd):
        coeff_list = [None, coeff] + [None] * i
        rec_d.append(pywt.waverec(coeff_list, w))
    if coef_type == 'd':
        return rec_d
    return rec_a
```

We need to slice the return value to have the same length with the input signal. Then we can get each component after decomposition.

```
X = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
rec_d = decomposite(X, 'd', 'db6', level=9)
# slice rec_d
print sum(rec_d )
```

Comment: This code didn't work for me. First, it has some problems with the function, it uses "mode" and "data" that were not passed ad parameters. Then the second code block doesn't show the slicing part. I created a sum using slice(18) index (for this example) and the results were really off.

Comment: how can this be applied to multilevel decomposition using the `pywt.wavedec()`  function and in the case where you have more than 2 signals?